# Android ChangeOverTime method freezing at runtime (but not consistently)

Tags: java, loops, freeze

So I am running into a problem with a function I made to slowly change the value of a monitored variable over time that is causing all the java logic to lock up. It doesn't seem to be producing an error or make the application crash so it must be getting stuck in the while loop or something but the logging isn't firing while it is locked so I am just very confused. If anyone can help me figure out how to diagnose what is causing the freezing that would be very much appreciated

EDIT: Turns out the problem was updating the UI from another thread, I manged to get it to crash and got the error and used a CountDownTimer instead of the background thread and now it is working fine. For those curious checkout my [GitHub](https://github.com/wSedlacek/wsedlacek.remind.com/commit/20973f7b6055d44b3340a56ffc0aeaafcb422c04) for this project.

Function in question:

```
public static void changeOverTime(final MonitoredVariable<Integer> tVar, final int tTo, final long tTime, final long tUpdateFreq) {
    if (tTime < tUpdateFreq) { Log.e(TAG, "Time must be greater then update freq."); }
    if (tVar == null) { Log.e(TAG, "Container cannot be null."); }
    else {
        final Thread tBackgroundThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                float tSteps = tTime / tUpdateFreq; // 2000/100 = 20
                float tInterval = (tTo - tVar.get()) / tSteps; // 67-175 = -108/20 = -5.4
                float tVal = tVar.get(); //175
                while (Math.round(tVal) != tTo) { //67(After 20 Times) != 67 -> FALSE
                    Debug.Log(TAG, "EQ: " + Math.round(tVal) + "?=" + tTo);
                    tVal += tInterval; // -5.4 * 20(Times) = -108+175 = 67
                    tryToSleep(tUpdateFreq); // 100ms * 20(Times) = 2000ms total
                    tVar.set(Math.round(tVal));
                }
            }
        });
        tBackgroundThread.start();
    }
}
```

Supporting Function:

```
private static void tryToSleep(long tTime) {
    try { sleep(tTime); }
    catch (InterruptedException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
}
```

Monitored Variable Class:

```
public class MonitoredVariable<Prototype> {
    protected Prototype mData;
    protected ChangeListener mListener;

    public MonitoredVariable(Prototype tData) {
        this(tData, null);
    }

    public MonitoredVariable(Prototype tData, ChangeListener tListener) {
        if (tListener != null) setListener(tListener);
        mData = tData;
    }

    public Prototype get() {
        return mData;
    }
    public void set(Prototype tData) {
        if (mData != tData) {
            mData = tData;
            notifyChange();
        }
    }

    public void setListener(ChangeListener tListener) {
        mListener = tListener;
    }
    public ChangeListener getListener() {
        return mListener;
    }
    public void notifyChange() {
        if (mListener != null) mListener.onChange();
    }
    public interface ChangeListener {
        void onChange();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
public static void init() {
    MonitoredVariable.ChangeListener tUpdateBackground = new MonitoredVariable.ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() { updateBackgroud();
        }
    };
    mTop = new MonitoredVariable[]{
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground),
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground),
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground)
    };
    mBottom = new MonitoredVariable[]{
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground),
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground),
            new MonitoredVariable<>(0, tUpdateBackground)
    };


    mAnimationLoop = new Handler();
    mAnimation = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Debug.Log(TAG, "RUNNING ANIMATION");
            final Random RNG = new Random();
            for (MonitoredVariable<Integer>[] tBackground: new MonitoredVariable[][] {mTop, mBottom}) {
                for (MonitoredVariable<Integer> tColor : tBackground) {
                    int tRandomColor = RNG.nextInt(255);
                    //tColor.set(tRandomColor);
                    Shift.changeOverTime(tColor, tRandomColor, 2000, 100);
                }
            }
            if(mAnimate.get()) {
                mAnimationLoop.postDelayed(mAnimation, 10000);
            }
        }
    };

    mAnimate = new MonitoredVariable<>(false, new MonitoredVariable.ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() {
            if (mAnimate.get()) mAnimationLoop.postDelayed(mAnimation, 0);
            else mAnimationLoop.removeCallbacks(mAnimation);
        }
    });
}

public static void setBackground(final Activity tActivity){
    final View tActivityBackground = tActivity.findViewById(R.id.background);
    mListener = new ChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChange() { tActivityBackground.setBackground(mBackground); }
    };

    notifyChange();
}

 private static void updateBackgroud() {
    int tTop = Color.argb(255, mTop[0].get(), mTop[1].get(), mTop[2].get());
    int tBottom = Color.argb(255, mBottom[0].get(), mBottom[1].get(), mBottom[2].get());
    int[] colors = {tTop, tBottom};
    mBackground = new GradientDrawable(GradientDrawable.Orientation.TOP_BOTTOM, colors);
    mBackground.setCornerRadius(0f);
    notifyChange();
}

public static void animateBackground(boolean tAnimate) {
    mAnimate.set(tAnimate);
}

public static void notifyChange() {
    if (mListener != null) mListener.onChange();
}

public interface ChangeListener {
    void onChange();
}
```